# How to keep SqlConnection open in an using block for an asynchronous query within the block?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asynchronous, sqlconnection

I am trying to make an asynchronous query in an using block with a `SqlConnection` variable.

This is my code:

```
using (var conn = GetNewConnection())
{
    var query = "DELETE FROM blah blah blah WHERE blah blah;"

    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[]
                {
                    new NpgsqlParameter("@a", A),
                    new NpgsqlParameter("@b", B)
                });
        cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

As seen above, the last line of the using block is an asynchronous task. In this situation, will the connection be open until the asynchronous query is complete? Why or why not?

What ought to be done to ensure the completion of an asynchronous task? What is a better way of doing it?

Comment: Make the method containing the using block `async` and use `await`

Comment: Thank you. I have a followup question. In doing so, will the execution of my program will be halted? Since this is a db operation, I would want my program to progress and not wait for the db operation- which will take a lot of time since i have 100k+ records.

Comment: if nothing is dependent on that operation then await that whole function on another thread.

Comment: Where/How is the function encapsulating this code run?

Comment: I usually put code into a background work and run the background worker asynchronously.  The use ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteNonQueryAsync.

Comment: @Nkoshi It is a method called by the main thread, but truly nothing is dependent on the execution of that operation. This code is for cleanup of some temporary records.
Also, there is another method that does a preventive check on `INSERT` to check for conflicts - in case this aforementioned method does not complete successfully. So this method is not critical in scope of the program run itself. However, it will affect performance if it errors or does not execute.

Comment: Short answer is as @RyanWilson says; i.e. don't.  Exiting the `using` _explicitly_ disposes the command and then the connection.  You _must_ await the result inside the `using`, and cannot elide the async-await here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encapsulate the entire code block in an async function, taking advantage of the async API and await any asynchronous function calls within.

For example

```
public async Task ExecuteMyNonQueryAsync() {    
    using (var conn = GetNewConnection()) {
        var query = "DELETE FROM blah blah blah WHERE blah blah;"
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn)) {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] {
                new NpgsqlParameter("@a", A),
                new NpgsqlParameter("@b", B)
            });
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The entire function can be run on a separate thread either using `Task.Run`

```
Task.Run(() => ExecuteMyNonQueryAsync());
```

or in an async event handler

```
public async void onSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    await ExecuteMyNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: That should do it. Thanks @Nkoshi

Comment: A followup question. Is it required that the method be a asynchronous method to run it in a new thread? Is it not sufficient to run a method in a new thread to make that method run asynchronously?